# List of and documentation for system calls for XNU kernel in OSX

Tags: macos, operating-system, system-calls

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of and documentation for the system calls available in the XNU kernel in OSX.  I've googled around quite a bit, but haven't been able to find anything of use.  As I understand the calling conventions match BSD, is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "official" list is at [Darwin page](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) at Apple. Specifically, see the file [`syscalls.master`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.20.48/bsd/kern/syscalls.master) in the XNU distribution. (If something you expect is missing, try a newer XNU version.)

The BSD part of the system calls comes from BSD, but there're mach calls which follow quite different conventions.

You'll definitely want to read Amit Singh's OS X kernel book, see [the book's website](http://osxbook.com/). It's rewritten for 10.4 and mainly for PPC, but still is the greatest detailed info you can get on the kernel.